# Is there a way to pass params to a script in TCL that is run using eval source?

Tags: tcl, eval

I have a script that calls:

```
 eval source \{$scriptfile\}
```

where $scriptfile is another TCL script.  Is there way to pass parameters to the script?  I'd like to do something like:

```
set sampleData "ID=14678934"
eval source \{$scriptfile\} $sampleData
```

I know that this isn't allowed but, is there a way to pass data to a script that is being executed using eval source?

Comment: No reason to use `eval`, and this is a horrible idea.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  Unfortunately, I did not have control over the existing code base.  It was written 10 years ago and I'm trying to make some minor changes to it until I can replace it outright.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a horrible practice to start.  It's much cleaner to call a proc that is within the script you're sourcing.

```
source script.tcl  ;# defines proc run_script_with_data
run_script_with_data $data
```

Comment: Another question.  This is being run with interp eval source.  Do you know how to access the data in a script run in another interpreter?  I apologize for the noob questions but, I'm new to TCL unfortunately.

Comment: @Corv1nus You mean a slave interpreter?  (as in, on created by the Tcl command `interp`)  Or one in a different process?

Comment: @Corv1nus  The master always has access to the data in the slave.  e.g. `set result [interp eval $slave set varname]` will retrieve the value stored in `varname` in the slave interpreter.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is given in the [Tclers Wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/_/welcome), in the following articles: [source with args](http://wiki.tcl.tk/10025) and [SrcFile](http://wiki.tcl.tk/14148).

The solution I like the most is `srcfile`:

```
proc srcfile { filename args } {
  global argv

  set argv $args
  source $filename
}
```

The only drawback of this approach is that it will modify `argv`, so you have to make sure you will not need it in the rest of the script, or backup and restore it.